# Sub-chapters in ePub file

Tags: xml, epub

The NCX file an ePub file can specify the chapters that have the book in ePub format.

It uses the following XML syntax:

```
<navPoint class="chapter" id="chapter1" playOrder="1">
      <navLabel><text>Chapter 1</text></navLabel>
      <content src="file1.xhtml"/>
</navPoint>
```

My question is, Can we create sub-chapters?, If so, how?.

I have searched Google and all I've found are very specific tools to perform these tasks. I do not want a tool, I want to know how to make sub-chapters in the NCX file.

Thank you,

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Change the depth to the number of levels

```
<meta content="2" name="dtb:depth"/>
```

Put a navPoint inside the navPoint that must contain the sublevel. Remember to close the navPoint!

```
<navPoint class="chapter" id="chapter1" playOrder="1">
      <navLabel><text>Chapter 1</text></navLabel>
      <content src="file1.xhtml"/>

  <navPoint class="subchapter" id="sub1" playOrder="2">
    <navLabel><text>Subchapter 1</text></navLabel>
    <content src="file2.xhtml"/>
  </navPoint>

</navPoint>
```